# Is there an SQL/NoSql deque or an easy way to implement TimeSeries Dada?

Tags: python, sql, preprocessor

**I don't know if this is possible**

I'm tring to Make a timeseries data set for finance.
[My_DataSet](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5EIBEX?period1=1577031834&period2=1608654234&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true)

The way I make it:

```
df = DataFrame(...path to the file)
#preprocessing...

sequential_data = []
sequences = 60

prev_days = deque( maxlen = sequences )
for i in df.values:
    prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
    if len(prev_days) == sequences:
        sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1:]])
```

I'm serching for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM x_TABLE group by 60 in deque
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? there are several time series databases that you can use

Comment: I don't use any... I have some csv files. Thats all. But i want to be able to scale the project with time. If you tell me the timeseries dabases i will gladly accespt your answer as valid

Comment: learn more about time series dbs more [here](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/what-are-time-series-databases-a3e847608f91)